# Image asset not overwriting existing icons, but disappearing

Tags: android, image, android-studio

In Android Studio when we create a new image asset, it says the icons will overwrite what is already there, but when we hit finish, the icons disappear on the computer instead.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm using reactnative. I see the tutorials, they add new `Image asset` and generate three icons: `ic_launcher`, `ic_launcher_round`, and `ic_launcher_foreground`. But I also got overwritten and it disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue for a long time.
But I resolve this by create the same image two times.
Provided for your reference.

Comment: No clue what that means.